# Is a teddy dead or alive?

Tags: language, science-in-society

All,

My daughter asked me today is my teddy real? I said well yes it's real but it's not like us, it's not alive it's... And stopped myself because it's not dead either.

I'm trying to find out if there is a word for something in between the dead and alive? If not, what is the teddy?

The definition of dead:

[http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dead?s=t](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deadhttp://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dead?s=t)

> no longer living; deprived of life

The definition of alive:

[http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alive?s=t](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alivehttp://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alive?s=t)

> having life; living; existing; not dead or lifeless.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Welcome to the site, Steven. Since this is a question about the English language, I believe this should be asked on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), rather than Worldbuilding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you want is inanimate. That is a weird linguistic hole in English.

Comment: Or "non-living".